# Flask - query on existing database

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I trying make app with is listing cities from pre-existing postgresql database.
So far I able connect to database and make a query, but results are returned u'string',

Here my models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Woonplaats(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'woonplaats'

    gid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    woonplaatsnaam = Column(String(80))

    def __init__(self, woonplaatsnaam=None):
        self.woonplaatsnaam = woonplaatsnaam

    def __repr__(self):
        return  '%r' % (self.woonplaatsnaam)
```

And views.py

```
from flask import render_template, request
from app import app
from app import db
from app.models import Woonplaats

@app.route('/citylist')
def citylist():
    results = db.session.query(Woonplaats).all()
    print(results) #only for test
    return render_template('city.html', results = results)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a `__str__` (or `__unicode__`), a class's `__repr__` will be used. When you print out the query set, you end up printing the `__repr__` of the `woonplaatsnaam` column. To print out the value of the column instead, add a `__str__` (or `__unicode__`) method.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.woonplaatsnaam

# for Python 2.x
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.woonplaatsnaam
```